# Html appended by jQuery is not displaced on source code

Tags: jquery, ajax

I had jQuery append html parsed from AJAX into a `<table>`. 
And I have to get the value fron class='msg'.
But it doesn't show on the source code. So I can't get the value. Can you explain me what my problem is?

```
function showHtml(data){
    var str = "<tr><td class='msg'>" + data.msg + "</td></tr>";
    $("tbody").append(str);
}

$.ajax({
  url: "----",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "html",
  data: {
    msg : msg 
  },
  success: function(json) {
    data = JSON.parse(json);
    showHtml(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: If you mean that it doesn't appear in the 'View Source' window - this is correct behaviour as that displays the HTML which was received from the server when the page was initially loaded. If you want to view the live state of the page, use the DOM inspector in the console. Also note that for some reason you set `dataType: 'html'`, then use `JSON.parse` in the `success` handler. If you're really returning JSON, just set `dataType: 'json'` and remove the `JSON.parse` line

Comment: when are you trying to access the msg class?  since it's an ajax request it's possible the request was not yet completed when you're trying to access it.

Comment: So I add "async : false" in ajax code. But another problem is when I reload the page I still can't access to that certain Class.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic created html should not be displayed at "View Source" window.

You can find the real time content at the inspector of each browser.

*Example Firefox: Right button page / Inspect -> Inspector Tab*

You can also work with the dynamic created content:

```js
function showHtml( data )
{
    var str = "<p>" + data + "</p>";
    $( "#myDiv" ).append( str );
}

var data = 'DATA TEST';
//Appending data
showHtml( data );
//Logging data
console.log( $( '#myDiv' ).html() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```